# Can I connect rectangle to C++ model?

Tags: c++, qml

I have connected QML's ListView to my C++ model and it updates when model changes which is cool. However I don't want to display my data in ListView bur rather in custom way in rectangle (ideally a plain view which doesn't exist).

How could I do this?

The issue I see obviously is `rectangle` is not a view and there is other plain view which allows custom drawing. Is there way around it?

**Addon**

Following up on the answer and comment, let me give context why I am doing it. I have various information and if I use list, I will have to use multiple lists on one screen which doesn't look good. What I want to implement is what I would call 'document view'. Header goes here, title goes there, data here and footer here. It is a custom presentation of my model's data.

@Folibis, I like your first point. It seems like if do something like:

```
Rectangle 
{
   Text { text: mySingleton.getFruitName() }
   Text { text: mySingleton.getFruitPrice() }
}
```

Note I have intentionally not included anchors or geometry to keep focus on my question but assume price appears next to fruit name.

Does this mean if I update fruit name or price of the exact same object in model else where in GUI, the above will be updated automatically?

Comment: You can use a `Flickable` with a `Repeater` as model if you don't want to use a `ListView` (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669856/howto-flick-a-qml-listview-horizontal-and-vertical/26840056#26840056)). You still have the `delegate` for the model items and the flicking ability without `ListView` features. Howeer the question is: what's the reason to not use `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to implement custom drawing. I can't really imagine what data can be supplied to Rectangle but anyway:

1. You can create custom Item in C++, for example singleton an fetch needed data from it.

```js
Rectangle {
    width: mySingleton.getWidth();
    height: mySingleton.getHeight();
    color: mySingleton.getColor();
}
```

2. You can create custom element derived from `QQuickPaintedItem`. All you need is reimplement `QQuickPaintedItem::​paint(QPainter * painter)` to draw your own rectangle. It's simpliest way to create ow element but not efficient since it uses `QPainter`.
3. Create custom element deriver from `QQuickItem`. You will need to reimplement `QSGNode * QQuickItem::​updatePaintNode(QSGNode * oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData * updatePaintNodeData)`. That's fast and reliable way but requires `OpenGL` experience.
4. Also as (1), but painting on `Canvas` element